# when copy/paste 'hello' from Word into textarea it becomes 018hello 019 after saving

Tags: ms-word, character-encoding, smart-quotes

I have in Word ‘hello’ and when I paste it I get 018hello 019 so the apostrophes turn into these strange characters.

The type of web application should not matter as the behaviour is different depending on the workstation I use.

I checked with Notepad, Excel and Wordpad and this issue does not occur, only for Word.

It should be a Word/IE setting .

Do you know which one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The quotation marks in word are not the "regular" quotation marks. Word automatically replaces quotations as you type them with fancy ones called "smart quotes". Since your browser does not understand smart quotes it replaces them.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the Word "smart quotes" feature. There should be a place to turn it off somewhere in the Word settings.

More information can be found at the [Quotation mark glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) Wikipedia article.